# ERR: cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to add foreign constraint to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE owners_carparks2users
#  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`agglomeration_id`) REFERENCES `carparks_tmp` (`agglomeration_id`), <- this works fine
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`carpark_id`) REFERENCES `carparks_tmp` (`carpark_id`)
```

But i receive error:

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Detailed Error (`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`):

> ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>   ------------------------ 2014-05-21 11:40:12 127938000 Error in foreign key constraint of table carparks/#sql-2e5_6a: FOREIGN KEY
>   (`carpark_id`) REFERENCES `carparks_tmp` (`carpark_id`): Cannot find
>   an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear
>   as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced
>   table do not match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type
>   of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and
>   such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new
>   tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

And my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE carparks_tmp (
  `agglomeration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carpark_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`agglomeration_id`,`carpark_id`)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS owners_carparks2users;
CREATE TABLE owners_carparks2users (
  `agglomeration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carpark_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Any help will be appeciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the erorr message says, you need to have `carpark_id` as the first column of an index on `carparks_tmp`.

So, you should add an index like:

```
  CREATE INDEX index_name
            ON carparks_tmp(carpark_id);
```

And then you'll be able to create the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't now that key that foreign key references to need to be indexed.